# Data missing in c# serial port

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, serial-port

I am communicating with DPS5020 power supply to get voltage and current. The SMPS data output does not contain any delimiter at the end of the packet so I think it is causing a problem. When I query the SMPS using serial terminal program, I get correct packet every time but when I am querying using a C# program, there is no data about 70% of the time. The in data packet size is 9 bytes long. I used `serial_port.Read(buffer, 0, 9)` but even then, there is error. Could anyone help me here? My code is below.

Main functions

```
    private void ovcRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] sendbyte = power2.PowerSupply_GetOVC();   // get over current value
        try
        {   serial_pow2.Write(sendbyte, 0, sendbyte.Length);
            SMPS2_timer.Enabled = true;
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }
        catch
        {   MessageBox.Show(serial_pow2.PortName + " port error");  }
    }

    private void ser_AVDD_DataRx(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (SMPS2_Tick == false)
        //    return;
        //SMPS2_Tick = true;

        byte[] readb = new byte[9];
        int s = serial_pow2.Read(readb, 0, 9);

        Action Receive = () =>
        {                    
            if (power2.getOutCur == true)
            {
                decimal volt, cur;
                power2.processOCP(readb, out volt, out cur);    // process over current raw data
                power2.getOutCur = false;
                if (volt != 99.99m && cur != 99.99m)
                    textBox2.Text = volt + " V,  " + cur + " A." + ";      " + readb[0].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[1].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[2].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[3].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[4].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[5].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[6].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[7].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[8].ToString("X2");
            }
        };
        this.Invoke(new Action(Receive));
        serial_pow2.DiscardInBuffer();
    }

    private void SMPS2_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SMPS2_timer.Enabled = false;
        SMPS2_Tick = true;
    }
```

Class Power2 functions.

```
   public byte[] PowerSupply_GetOVC()
    {
        UInt16 CRC_high = 0;
        UInt16 CRC_low = 0;
        int i = 0;

        getOutCur = true;
        int[] supplySet = { 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x02 };       // get output volt, current
        byte[] sendbyte = new byte[supplySet.Length + 2];
        Modbus_CRC_Check(supplySet, out CRC_high, out CRC_low);
        for (i = 0; i < supplySet.Length; i++)
            sendbyte[i] = Convert.ToByte(supplySet[i]);
        sendbyte[i++] = Convert.ToByte(CRC_low);
        sendbyte[i++] = Convert.ToByte(CRC_high);
        return sendbyte;
    }

    public void processOCP(byte[] readb, out decimal volt, out decimal cur)
    {
        try
        {
            int t = readb[3];
            t <<= 8;
            int y = readb[4];
            int vol = (t + y);
            volt = (decimal)vol / 100;

            t = readb[5];
            t <<= 8;
            y = readb[6];
            int curr = (t + y);
            cur = (decimal)curr / 100;
        }
        catch
        {
            volt = 99.99m;
            cur = 99.99m;
        }
    }

    void Modbus_CRC_Check(int[] data_array, out UInt16 CRC_high, out UInt16 CRC_low)
    {
        UInt16 crc = 65535;

        for (int i = 0; i < data_array.Length; i++)
        {
            crc ^= (ushort)data_array[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if ((crc & 1) != 0)
                {
                    crc >>= 1;
                    crc ^= 0xA001;
                }
                else
                {
                    crc >>= 1;
                }
            }
        }            
        CRC_low = (ushort)(crc & 0x00FF);
        CRC_high = (ushort)(crc >> 8);
    }
```

When using terminal, the input and output data are :

```
input command:      01 03 00 02 00 02 65 CB
output data :       01 03 04 00 62 00 00 5B ED
```

Using C# when values are not correct:

```
input command:   01 03 00 02 00 02 65 CB
output data1:    01 03 04 00 62 00 00 5B ED
output data2:    01 03 04 00 00 00 00 00 00
output data3:    01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I tried setting `ReadTimeout` values and using timer check at the beginning to Serial receive event but the result is same.

Comment: Why are you reading 9 bytes when you are only going to get 8 bytes?

Comment: Input byte length is 8 bytes, output is 9 bytes. serial_pow2.Read(readb, 0, 9); reads 9 bytes i suppose.

Comment: Yes.  It will sit until it gets a ninth byte.

Comment: @sujan_014 Do you read output data 1~3 AFTER request sent? Eg: Request, read output 1, Request, read output 2...etc. Your sample code seems like not checking return value `int s` of `SerialPort.Read`. I'll suggest you check `int s` to see if data fully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it. I had been suspecting that program was receiving data in fragments. If the data length is not 9 I stored data in temporary buffer. In the next read the latest data is concatenated to temporary buffer in serialport event handling. Now I get correct data.

Here is how I did.

```
    private void ovcRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] sendbyte = power1.PowerSupply_GetOVC();            
        try
        {   serial_pow1.Write(sendbyte, 0, sendbyte.Length);    }
        catch
        {   MessageBox.Show(serial_pow1.PortName + " port error");  }

        sendbyte = power2.PowerSupply_GetOVC();
        try
        {   serial_pow2.Write(sendbyte, 0, sendbyte.Length);
            query = true;
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }
        catch
        {   MessageBox.Show(serial_pow2.PortName + " port error");  }
    }

    byte[] readb = new byte[100];
    int cnt = 0;
    int prevlen = 0;
    int newlen = 0;

    private void ser_AVDD_DataRx(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {          

        int bytes = serial_pow2.BytesToRead;
        byte[] readc = new byte[bytes];
        serial_pow2.Read(readc, 0, bytes);
        if (bytes < 9)
        {
            if (query == true)
            {
                readc.CopyTo(readb, 0);
                prevlen = readc.Length;
                query = false;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    readc.CopyTo(readb, prevlen);
                    newlen = prevlen + readc.Length;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(readc.Length + "/n" + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            readc.CopyTo(readb, 0);
        }
        Action Receive = () =>
        {
            if (readc.Length == 9)
            {
                prevlen = 0;
                cnt = 0;
                decimal volt, cur;
                power2.processOCP(readc, out volt, out cur);
                power2.getOutCur = false;
                textBox2.Text = volt + " V,  " + cur + " A." + ";      " + readb[0].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[1].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[2].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[3].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[4].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[5].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[6].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[7].ToString("X2") + " " + readb[8].ToString("X2");
                //if (volt != 99.99m && cur != 99.99m)                        
            }
            else
            {
                textBox2.Text = "";
                byte[] temp = new byte[newlen];

                for (int b = 0; b < newlen; b++)
                {
                    textBox2.Text += readb[b].ToString("X2") + " ";
                }
            }
        };
        this.Invoke(new Action(Receive));            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be caused by `serial_pow2.DiscardInBuffer()`.

Unless you know there is no data you need in buffer, don't discard it.

If you make two request and just read one response, serial_pow2.DiscardInBuffer() will discard the second response in buffer.

Since your snippet is initialed by button, I can't assure how do you make request and get response.

My suggestion is not using DiscardInBuffer unless you're initializing or closing your application, or you might lose data.